# Place Primary key inside JSON response

Tags: python, django, postman, jsonresponse

The JSON response i'm getting is as below.

[image]

In my code i'am trying to fetch the list from the db, as per above img. In the result `primary key` is coming outside of the fields for each record. How can i place it inside the fields for every record like.

```
"results":[
  "fields":{
      "pk": "F09087687633",
      "company_name": "Tata",
  }
]
```

Below is my code:

**views.py** (In below code for loop is to remove app name from the results, same i use to remove primary key, it is working but how can i place it inside for each fields.)

```
@csrf_exempt
def fleet_owner_list(request):
 page_number = json.loads(request.body)
 records,total_pages = FleetOwner.get_all_owners(page_number)
 for data in range(len(records)):
   del records[data]['model']
 returnObject = {
       "page" : page_number,
       "total_results":len(records),
       "total_pages":total_pages,
       "status" : messages.RETRIVAL_SUCCESS,
       "message" : messages.FLEETOWNER_DATA_RETRIEVE_SUCCESS,
       "results" : records
   }
```

**models.py**

```
@classmethod
   def get_all_owners(cls,page_number):
      data = cls.objects.filter(is_deleted = False)
      page_numbers = page_number
      pegination_result, total_page_count = list_paginate(data, page_numbers)
      data = serializers.serialize("json", pegination_result)
      data = json.loads(data)
      return data, total_page_count
```

**paginator.py** (This is a common function i'm using for all the list functions to perform django pagination.)

```
def list_paginate(data,page_numbers):
     paginator = Paginator(data,10)
     page = page_numbers
     try :
           records = paginator.page(page)
     except PageNotAnInteger:
           records = paginator.page(1)
     except EmptyPage:
           records = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
     return records, paginator.num_pages
          pegination_result, total_page_count = list_paginate(data, page_numbers)
          data = serializers.serialize("json", pegination_result)
          data = json.loads(data)
          return data, total_page_count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default this is how Django serialize a queryset into JSON Objects. [The Django documentation also state the same](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json). **The whole collection is just represented as an array and the objects are represented by JSON objects with three properties: “pk”, “model” and “fields”. “fields” is again an object containing each field’s name and value as property and property-value respectively.** i.e.,

```
[
    {
        "pk": "4b678b301dfd8a4e0dad910de3ae245b",
        "model": "sessions.session",
        "fields": {
            "expire_date": "2013-01-16T08:16:59.844Z",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

If you look at the [`Serializer`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/core/serializers/python.py#L14) class implementation you can find a [`get_dump_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/core/serializers/python.py#L35) method which is responsible for the final JSON output for an object. i.e.,

```
def get_dump_object(self, obj):
    data = {'model': str(obj._meta)}
    if not self.use_natural_primary_keys or not hasattr(obj, 'natural_key'):
        data["pk"] = self._value_from_field(obj, obj._meta.pk)
    data['fields'] = self._current
    return data
```

In other teams this is the method responsible for the below format,

```
{
        "pk": "pk",
        "model": "model",
        "fields": {
            "field1": "2013-01-16T08:16:59.844Z",
            ...
        }
    }
```

Since you want the `pk` field inside the `fields` you should create your own JSON serializer class and override the [`get_dump_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/core/serializers/python.py#L35) method like the below one,

```
>>> import json
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JSONSerializer
>>> 
>>> class MyCustomSerializer(JSONSerializer):
...     def get_dump_object(self, obj):
...             data = {'model': str(obj._meta)}
...             data['fields'] = self._current
...             if not self.use_natural_primary_keys or not hasattr(obj, 'natural_key'):
...                     data['fields'].update({'pk': self._value_from_field(obj, obj._meta.pk)})
...             return data
... 
>>> pprint(json.loads(MyCustomSerializer().serialize(User.objects.all())))
[{'fields': {'date_joined': '2019-07-13T05:52:37.885Z',
             'email': 'user1@gmail.com',
             'first_name': 'User',
             'groups': [],
             'is_active': True,
             'is_staff': False,
             'is_superuser': False,
             'last_login': None,
             'last_name': '1',
             'password': '',
             'pk': 1,
             'user_permissions': [],
             'username': ''},
  'model': 'auth.user'}]
# You can see that `pk` is now inside the 'fields' key.
>>> json.loads(MyCustomSerializer().serialize(User.objects.all()))[0]['fields']['pk']
1
```

Comment: How to access the fields by using pk value ? Lets say var is the json object. var[0] gives teh first row. lets say pk = 232 for index 0. i tried var[232] var.232 but doesn't work